# Rails: model scope filtered by instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Cover model, in the `cover.rb` file, I also define a method called `size` which returns an integer representing 'small, intermediate, large'.
My question is how can I retrieve all the small/intermediate/large covers?
My guess is to use `scope`, but I cannot figure out how to pass the `size` method as a condition.

```
class Cover < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :length, :width

  # TODO
  scope :small
  scope :intermediate
  scope :large

  # I have simplified the method for clarity.
  # 0 - small; 1 - intermediate;  2 - large
  def size
    std_length = std_width = 15
    if length < std_length && width < std_width
      0
    elsif length > std_length && width > std_width
      2
    else
      1
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could work:

```
class Cover < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :length, :width

  scope :of_size, lambda{ |size| 
                          case size
                            when :small
                              where('width < 15 AND height < 15')
                            when :large
                              where('width > 15 AND height > 15')
                            when :intermediate
                              where('(width < 15 AND height > 15) OR (width > 15 AND height < 15)')
                            else
                              where(id: -1) # workaround to return empty AR::Relation
                        }

  def size
    std_length = std_width = 15
    return :small if length < std_length && width < std_width
    return :large if length > std_length && width > std_width
    return :intermediate
  end

end
```

And use it like this:

```
Cover.of_size(:small) # => returns an array of Cover with size == small
```

To make it work with several arguments:

```
# in the model:
scope :of_size, lambda{ |*size| all.select{ |cover| [size].flatten.include?(cover.size) } }
# how to call it:
Cover.of_size(:small, :large) # returns an array of covers with Large OR Small size
```

Comment: You're welcome :) You could extend it with several arguments, and you could use it like `Cover.of_size(:small, :large)`

Comment: BTW, is there any solution to return ActiveRecord::Relation objects? I found that the paginate method fails with array...

Comment: add `where(nil)` at the end, probably like this: `Cover.of_size(:small).where(nil)` ### Doesn't work actually

Comment: It says `NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0xc396280>`

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it is not using the `select` method (which was using a lot of resources: get all the Cover, translate them into Ruby objects, test each one). The scope is better now, but you should use class variables for the max_width & max_height ;)

Comment: I didn't read the update carefully. I've simplified my size method. The real method involves many other calculations, and that's why I haven't figured out how to use 'where' clause appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you the simplest solution would be a class method:

```
def self.small
  Cover.all.select {|c| c.size == 0}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering passing one of three sizes, you might as well call one of three scopes.  It'll be more readable.

```
scope :small, where('width < 15 AND height < 15')
scope :large, where('width > 15 AND height > 15')
scope :intermediate, where('(width < 15 AND height > 15) OR (width > 15 AND height < 15)')
```